# Is there a way I can setup a batch file or script file I can run to compile my .NET so I can edit in Notepad++ alone?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I know I will miss so much of Visual Studio but I am getting really sick of it crashing all the time and being slow, PLUS it is always changing things in my repository that I don't want to change, so I want to just edit with Notepad++. However, now I will have to load up VS just to build things. Is there a way I can build from command line and make a script for it and what not? Will it show the compile errors?

Please don't try to troubleshoot VS for me, I am just asking what is in the question and the rest was just given for context and so nobody was like 'Y U NO RIKE VIZAL STUDIA?'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

build:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "**PATH TO YOUR SOLUTION FILE**"
help: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /help

Answer (score 2):

What you need is directly calling csc.exe, the C# compiler (which is called by the build system of Visual Studio, anyways). If you ever worked with GCC, it is quite similar except that options are passed Windows-style with / signs instead of -- and there are no object files or additional linking. The MSDN library has documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx.

Generally, you'd need something like:

```
csc /target:exe /out:Something.exe *.cs
```

plus any /reference's you would add in Visual Studio.

If your project is large, it may be uncomfortable to maintain a .bat file to do the compilation, so a build tool like [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) may be needed, which is quite similar to the Ant used for Java.

This is of course if you want to eliminate Visual Studio entirely. Otherwise, Snowbear's solution of invoking MSBuild.exe will be just as fine.

Comment: MSBUILD isn't part of VisualStudio, its part of the .Net framework.  So using it achieves "eliminate VS entirely".  Using csc.exe is a good suggestion, but msbuild.exe is going to give you nant-like customization and flexibility.  Don't want to discourage the OP from msbuild by lumping it in w VS

Comment: I would not recommend taking this approach. Better is to just create MSBuild Project files and let it handle the building.